# How to use Selector0 class of Flutter Provider package and when to use?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, state-management

I am going to through the [Provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) in detail, but I could not find any example of using **Selector0** class.

Could anyone tell me the use case of **Selector0** class with a simple example?

Comment: If you're just starting on Provider, I highly recommend you look at RiverPod instead.  Both written by the same guy.  And RiverPod is better along nearly every important dimension.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz It is not like that, I am looking for a better package. I am just exploring all the available options in the Provider package itself. I know, I can simply go for getx or BLoC as well.